# How does AWS charge me for my Elastic Beanstalk applications when not doing anything

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created a elastic beanstalk environment and it created an EC2 instance. Then I thought I don't actually need this yet so I'll stop the EC2 instance, but then it seemed to start another one.

So my question is if I have an EB instance will I be charged by the hour for the underlying EC2 image all the time or only when the the service it provides is being access via the public elasticip. And if Im charged all the time is there a way to halt a elastic beanstalk application or only delete it or instantiate to a new environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [auto scaling feature](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.as.html) of Elastic Beanstalk will automatically start another instance if a current instance continues to fail a health check. Stopping individual instances outside of the environment will cause failed health checks and trigger a new instance to be spun up.

You will be charged when the components within the environment are running as stated by Amazon [here](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/pricing/):

> There is no additional charge for Elastic Beanstalk – you only pay for the underlying AWS resources (e.g. Amazon EC2, Amazon S3) that your application consumes.

You can completely stop an environment through the CLI. I gave [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397132/stop-and-start-elastic-beanstalk-services/20403120#20403120) to a previous question about starting and stopping Elastic Beanstalk:

> The [EB command line interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-get-started.html) has an `eb stop` command. [Here](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/06/aws-elastic-beanstalk-simplfied-command-line-eb.html) is a little bit about what the command actually does:
>
> > The eb stop command deletes the AWS resources that are running your application (such as the ELB and the EC2 instances). It however leaves behind all of the application versions and configuration settings that you had deployed, so you can quickly get started again. Eb stop is ideal when you are developing and testing your application and don’t need the AWS resources running over night. You can get going again by simply running eb start.

Comment: thanks, bit silly that its not available from the website though, but perhaps that is done on purpose to make Amazon some extra dosh.

Comment: You _can_ use the website. You simply need to terminate the entire environment from within the Elastic Beanstalk tab of the AWS Console, instead of the EC2 tab.