# Pause an Elastic Beanstalk app environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to shut down the app servers while I upgrade the database.

Is there a way to pause or stop the app servers without terminating/destroying the environment?

Can I just go to the Elastic Beanstalk load balancer and change that temporarily without any issues or consequences to the Elastic Beanstalk configurations or the way it manages its servers?

Comment: It used to support CLI commands 'eb stop' and 'eb start' but no longer does. Suspect you need to take snapshots of data, then terminate and re-create the environment from the same version. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.terminating.html.

Comment: @jarmod - I think pausing an environment can now effectively be achieved with [eb scale](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-scale.html), see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32215124/45773) for details.

Comment: If there's only one instance, wouldn't it be possible to just stop the underlying EC2 instance from the EC2 console?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This is the only method that worked for me.

1) Go to the environment you want to pause on [AWS Management Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home)

2) Select "Configuration"

3) Open "Capacity"

4) Scroll all the way down to "Time-based Scaling"

5) Click the "Add schedule action" button

6) Set the action to few minutes in the future (recommended: 5 minutes so environment has time to reset), give it a name (for example "terminate") and set minimum and maximum instances to '0':

[image: New scheduled action]

> Note that times are set in UTC. You can use [time.is/UTC](https://time.is/UTC) to determine the current UTC.

This would create an error that would shut down your environment so you won't have to pay for it.
Any other methods suggested just create a error at time of applying so it doesn't pass through and environment would still work.

To re-enable the environment, just schedule another action with instance min 1 and max 4 for example (those are the defaults).

Comment: This doesn't work now. Beanstalk validates the config first and jus sends a service message with the error, without applying the config.

Comment: @JorgeOrpinel Are you sure you are using scaling environment and not "single-instance"? I'm using this on daily basis (scheduled)...

Comment: You're right. My scheduled action was never run because I didn't set the time properly! I didn't consider that you have to use UTC time. https://time.is/UTC is useful for this B)  It seems to work after all.

Comment: @JorgeOrpinel Glad that it's still valid and thank's for improving the answer. :)

Comment: It worked for me but I had to also put the desired capacity to zero. But yeah nice answer

Comment: What if I have some files manually installed on the host? Set the instance 1 will wipe them out I think.

Comment: This will terminate EC2 instances, not the environment itself. You will still pay an hourly rate for your load balancer.

Answer (score 20):

From [AWS What's New blog Dec 16, 2016](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/12/aws-elastic-beanstalk-support-for-restoring-terminated-environments/):

> You can now restore AWS Elastic Beanstalk environments that have been
> terminated. You can restore Elastic Beanstalk environments within 42
> days of their termination, and the restored environments will retain
> the original environment IDs, CNAMEs, application versions, and
> configuration options.
>
> You can use the Elastic Beanstalk console, EB
> CLI, AWS CLI, SDK, and API to restore environments that have been
> terminated. Visit the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-management-rebuild.html) to learn more.

Answer (score 14):

Depending on how you orchestrate your [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) environment, this can be achieved with the EB Command Line Interface's [eb scale](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-scale.html) command for example:

> Scales the environment to always run on a specified number of
>   instances, setting both the minimum and maximum number of instances to
>   the specified number.

- The underlying Auto Scaling settings are also accessible via the Elastic Beanstalk Console's 'Configuration' section, specifically the 'Scaling' tile.

---

Alternatively you can always manually scale down the auto scaling group yourself by setting the minimum and desired number of instances to zero.

- This can be achieved via the [AWS Management Console](https://aws.amazon.com/console/) (accessible via the EC2 section, bottom left features a link to `Auto Scaling Groups`), the [AWS Command Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) (the [autoscaling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/index.html) reference features resp. commands), or also programmatically via the [AWS SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/), in case you want to include it into your deployment automation.

Comment: hmm it seems like it won't let me set it to 0

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey - Have you set both the minimum and desired number to 0? I specifically tried that because I wasn't 100% positive on the resp. EB behavior either, and there might be some constraints in this regard indeed - however, it worked fine for me, the environment has simply been marked as red aka unhealthy thereafter, but other than that it just worked and stayed like that until I terminated it a few hours later.

Comment: yeah I tried that and it said that max can't be smaller then min and won't let me set 0 on either.

Comment: That's odd, what solution stack are you using? Either way, an alternative might be to go to the Auto Scaling Group management in the EC2 Console (bottom left from the dashboard) and adjust the resp. ASG from there - this is not under control of Elastic Beanstalk, thus _might_ circumvent any EB specific constraints.

Comment: @SteffenOpel scale works if it is a load-balanced server. If not, you would get this message:
`The environment is currently a single-instance. Do you want to change to a load-balancing environment?
WARNING: If you choose yes, the environment and your application will be temporarily unavailable.`

Answer (score 6):

Setting `min` and `max` to `0` under `Configuration > Capacity > Auto Scaling Group` will shutdown the EC2 instance.

[image]

Event entry:
`There are no instances. Auto Scaling group desired capacity is set to zero.`

Comment: **NOTE:** this doesn't work if you have rolling updates setup (_**Error:** "The minimum instances in service for rolling updates (1) should be less than the maximum instance count for the Autoscaling group (1)"_); to fix this also change `Rolling updates and deployments > Configuration updates > Rolling update type` to `Disabled`.

Comment: You will still be paying for the load balancer. I got hit with this for months.

Answer (score 1):

I could only make this work using the `aws-cli` by setting the ASG values directly. Scale up to 1 instance:

```
aws autoscaling update-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name <ASG-Name> 
  --min-size=1 --max-size=1 --region <region>
```

Then to pause, reduce the min size in the ASG to 0:

```
aws autoscaling update-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name <ASG-Name> 
  --min-size=0 --max-size=1 --region <region>`
```

Then set the desired capacity to 0 to kill the instance:

```
aws autoscaling set-desired-capacity --auto-scaling-group-name <ASG-Name>
  --desired-capacity 0 --region <region>
```