# Can I stop elastic beanstalk environments at night?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'd like to apply a "lights out" policy for the development Elastic Beanstalk environments. Saw this from 2 years ago: [Stop and Start Elastic Beanstalk Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397132/stop-and-start-elastic-beanstalk-services). 
Is there *currently* a way to simply switch an env on/off and not loose the CNAME? and not do much anyway? Just recreate the instances/ELBs/DBs in the morning? or after the weekend?

Other advice in case it's not possible?

Thanks

Comment: There are third party services that provide this. Amazon does not provide an "easy" way to do this. You could create your own method by scripting AWS API calls and running your script on a schedule.